# GAE - rpc and HashMap<K,V> field

Tags: google-app-engine, gwt, gwt-rpc

I tested my gwt app in eclipse and it worked fine; Then I tried to deploy my test app to gae... That what exception I can see in gae logs after each rpc call :

> java.lang.RuntimeException: java.io.NotSerializableException

... so I am still looking the reason; but there is a point which make me confused cause one of my rpc-callback objects contains HashMap as one of its fields;

```
public abstract class Report implements Serializable{}
public abstract class Message implements Serializable{}
public class ErrorMessage extends Message{}

public final class Error extends Report
{
 private HashMap<String,ErrorMessage> msgs;//<---?

 //...
 public void setMsg(HashMap<String,ErrorMessage> msgs){this.msgs=msgs;}
 public HashMap<String,ErrorMessage> getMsg(){return this.msgs;}
}
```

...So my question is...

does gae supports java.util.HashMap ? And if not what is the most optimal collections alternative?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It might be the "ErrorMessage" object that's not serializable.

Comment: Why? I mean why do you think so? It works fine on local machine in eclipse but gae throws the exception because of the ErrorMessage ?

Comment: I think so because you have a SerializableException. It means one of the object or you shared object itself is not serializable. If you are not the author of the ErrorMessage class check it's the same version on both GAE and local and that your GWT version is the same too. Serializable means implementing the proper interface but also having a no-arg constructor and that all its fields are supported by GWT client-side implementation and are neither final nor transient. Since I can't see that from the code in your question I suggest you double-check that.

Comment: and AFAIK java.util.HashMap is supported.

Comment: you mean the sdk supports the (java.util)'s HashMap?

Comment: Yep, they use it in the official doc https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/cloud-sql/?hl=fr search for "hashmap" on the page.

Comment: OK but what about inheritance? Are there some limitations?

Comment: I don't get the question. ErrorMessage will inherit its super class interface but that is not enough to be "serializable".

Comment: OK I got it; I tried to include the java.util.HashMap into my another test rpc call/callback method; So it gives no exception; So you are right the HashMap is really serializable event in gae; Thanks

Comment: You are welcome. Did you got the error because you were missing a no-arg constructor or something similar ?

Comment: Perhaps you are right. But I am still debugging it so if something goes wrong in this direction I shall add some related details. Thank you